# nd4j arrays return incorrect rank

Tags: java, dl4j, nd4j

When I create an nd array from a 1d `float[]` it has rank 2.

```
INDArray array = Nd4j.create(new float[] {0,1,2,3,4,5});
int rank = array.rank(); // Is 2!
```

From the documentation this is supposed to be rank 1: http://nd4j.org/userguide#createfromjava

Any ideas how can I create a rank 1 INDArray?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is a big deal. You don't need to have 1 rank arrays. We built nd4j like this on purpose. This avoids all sorts of edge cases.

A 2 rank array of shape 1 x 1 is still a 1 length array.